# confusion between overlapping lines gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following .plt file:

```
set term post eps enh col 'Helvetica' 16 dl 3 size 10,10

# x-axis
set xlabel "classes"
set xtics 10

# y-axis
set ylabel "Accuracy [Percentage]"
set ytics 5

#set grid

# Legend
set key spac 1.25
set key below

# Accuracies vs classes of flowers as 0,1,2..100
# -----------------------------------
set out "AccuracyVSFlowersclasses.eps"

plot "inceptionresnet.dat" u 1:2 w p lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "green" notitle,\
 "mobilenet.dat" u 1:2 w p lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "red" notitle ,\
 "nasnet.dat" u 1:2 w p lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "yellow" notitle,\
 "resnet50.dat" u 1:2 w p lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "magenta " notitle,\
 "resnet152.dat" u 1:2 w p lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" notitle,\
 "inceptionresnet.dat" u 1:2 w l lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "green" t "inception-resnet",\
 "mobilenet.dat" u 1:2 w l lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "red" t "mobilenet" ,\
 "nasnet.dat" u 1:2 w l lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "yellow" t "nasnet",\
 "resnet50.dat" u 1:2 w l lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "magenta " t "resnet50",\
 "resnet152.dat" u 1:2 w l lw 6 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" t "resnet152"
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

My question is about how to make the plot clearer, by having the lines more differentiated among them. I've tried to use less values of x but I had to remove manually from the .dat files and it was too long and the result not good. I've also tried to use smooth option but it results in a oversmoothed graph which doesn't even take into considerations the values of accuracy below 70% and above 90%.

What kind of solution do you have in mind to get a more clearer graph?

Comment: Plotting so much similar data on top of each other is always going to do this. I would recommend linewidth (lw) a little smaller. But really, can you do multiple plots? Look into multiplot.

Comment: To skip values you don't have to delete lines from your data file, just use the `every` keyword to the plot command. If you really have to show all this data in a single plot I would try a two-dimensional [heat map](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html).